# open veracrypt file with cryptsetup/luks

Tags: luks, truecrypt, veracrypt

Can cryptsetup be used to open a veracrypt file like crypsetup can open luks?  What is the correct process ?

Want to make sure other software can open veracrypt file , command line or gui is fine, as long as it can open a veracrypt file.

---

Tried:

> `$ sudo cryptsetup tcryptOpen '/media/path/to/veracrypt/file' stuff`

> `$ sudo cryptsetup --type --tcryptOpen ''/media/path/to/veracrypt/file' stuff`

> `cryptsetup tcryptOpen '/media/path/to/veracrypt/file' stuff`

Thanks to @Vojtech Trefny below command seemed to work but with an error:

> ~$ sudo cryptsetup --type tcrypt --veracrypt open '/media/path/to/veracrypt/file' stuff

> > Enter passphrase for /media/...:

> > Device '/media/path/to/veracrypt/file' is too small.

password was able to open the veracrypt file using veracrypt, but not using cryptsetup....

---

Additional Note:

This is command allowed me to access veracrypt/truecrypt files using * cryptsetup *

```
$ sudo cryptsetup --type tcrypt open container-to-mount container-name
```

[kenfavors.com](https://kenfavors.com/code/how-to-open-a-truecrypt-container-using-cryptsetup/) has a simple example page that may be useful to anyone having similar problem described above

Comment: No, LUKS is totally different format. See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/203675/199910

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably mistaking LUKS and cryptsetup. [LUKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) is a disk encryption format/metadata specification and cryptsetup is a tool (and library) for working with encrypted devices. It was first started for LUKS/dm-crypt but it also supports other formats including TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt, BitLocker and loopaes.

To unlock a VeraCrypt device using cryptsetup use `cryptsetup tcryptOpen <device> <name>`, details about TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt support are available in the man page, section [TCRYPT (TrueCrypt-compatible and VeraCrypt) EXTENSION](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html#TCRYPT_(TrueCrypt-compatible_and_VeraCrypt)_EXTENSION).

Comment: Thanks - yes i was confusing cryptsetup with luks........but tried a few different variations of the command you provided, finally ~$ sudo cryptsetup --type tcrypt --veracrypt open <device> <name> to work accepting password, but fails with error   

Device /media/path/to/veracrypt/file is too small.

Answer (score 0):

- You first need to make your veracrypt file into a loop device.

  ```shell
  ls -l /dev/loo*
  ```
- Pick one not presently used or make a new one:

  ```shell
  losetup /dev/loop8 /your/encrypted/veracrypt/file.hc
  ```
- Cryptsetup as you would for any other veracrypt device eg:

  ```shell
  cryptsetup open --type tcrypt --veracrypt-query-pim /dev/loop8 unlockeddevice
  ```
- Unlock with your PIM and password. Then mount:

  ```shell
  mount /dev/mapper/unlockeddevice /mnt/myveracryptdrive
  ```